# Limit appearing certain pattern only one time in string

Tags: java, regex

I use follwoing regex to match a String as follows

```
((\d\d-){2}\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d)?(\s*)MONX(\s*)((\d\d-){2}\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d)?


MONX  04-12-2016 00:30
```

OR

```
04-12-2016 00:30 MONX
```

But I do not want to match following type of Strings

```
 04-12-2016 00:30 MONX 04-12-2016 00:30
```

How to limit

```
((\d\d-){2}\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d)
```

only to occur once in the String?

Comment: Try [`String pat = "^(?:((?:\\d\\d-){2}\\d{4})\\s(\\d\\d:\\d\\d)\\s*MONX|MONX\\s*((?:\\d\\d-){2}\\d{4})\\s(\\d\\d:\\d\\d))$"`](https://regex101.com/r/lG2pD0/1)

Comment: Can't do that I'm adding MONX part dynamically. For ex: MONX|KEMP|TIME| this will go for 10 to 20 times.  So if there any other way? If not there'll be lot of code

Comment: Why not use a `[A-Z]+` instead? Or `[A-Z]{2,}` - place some minimum number of occurrences.

Comment: I'm passing this to database to get hits for certain names with time stamps in front or at the end. select * from table where regexp_like(name, '^(KEMP|XYZ|PQR)(\s*)((\d\d-){2}\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d)?$');

Comment: Does the database support lookaheads? You might try [`^(?=\D*(?:\d\d-){2}\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d)(?=.*MONX)`](https://regex101.com/r/lG2pD0/2).

Comment: Are you using Java regexes, or those of a database program?  If it's a database, which one?  This is important because DB regexes tend to be extremely limited in functionality (but also extremely fast).

Comment: 04-12-2016 00:30MONX above doesn't match any of it. What does the lookaheads do? Oracle 11g

Comment: Try this: [`^(\s*((\d\d-\d\d-\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d)()|(MONX|KEMP|TIME|WHATEVER)())){2}$\4\6`](https://regex101.com/r/cZ0rX2/1).  I can't test it in Oracle, but if it works for you I'll post an answer explaining it.

Comment: It doesn't work it in oracle though , but if you could give an explanation it would be nice

Comment: The idea is to use empty groups as check boxes.  If the reference to group 4 succeeds, then group 3 (the timestamp) must have matched at some point, because they're in the same branch; same for groups 6 and 5 (the name).  It works in some of the Perl-derived flavors, like Java, PCRE, and .NET, but I'm not really surprised it doesn't work in Oracle.  Looks like you'll have to spell out both parts twice, or take a different approach, possibly involving multiple stages.

Comment: If you know that the faulty cases @AlanMoore added tests against (**only** two time stamps **or** *words*) won't appear, then what about a simplification of his RE - `^((\d\d-\d\d-\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d)\s*|(MONX|KEMP|TIME|WHATEVER)\s*){2}$`. It handles your example strings correctly.  That's pretty basic so - does that work in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The simples way I can think of is to test for one *or* the other;

```
((?:\d\d-){2}\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d\s*MONX)|(MONX\s*(?:\d\d-){2}\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d)
```

[See it here.](https://regex101.com/r/zT7dB8/1)

Regards.

Comment: Can't do that I'm adding MONX part dynamically. For ex: MONX|KEMP|TIME| this will go for 10 to 20 times.  So if there any other way? If not there'll be lot of code